# An error when passing a parameter in a route laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

this is my code

1. route.php

`Route::get('test/{id}','testController@test');`

2. testController.php

`public function test($id){ return('test'); }`

1. test.blade.php

   `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
        <title>a</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <img src="myPath/myImage.jpg">
     </body>
    </html>`

***The result:***   the image cant be load

**note:** when i deleted the 'id' parameter it has worked perfectly

Comment: it's because you are using a relative url for your image source. Update the image source to an absolute url.

Comment: You need to use `href="{{ URL::to('yourfile')}}"`. You should place your images in public folder. If you will create folder img in your public folder then you need to something like this: `href="{{ URL::to('img\imgname.png')}}"`

Comment: thank you  it work =D =D @forexknight

Comment: Then accept my answer on the bottom that anyone can know that case has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution :** i have changed the value of the src attribute

```
 <img src="{{URL::to('myPath/myImage.jpg')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you are getting?

You will also probably want to change the return value of testController@test to something along the lines of this so you can actually pass the variable to the view.

```
return view('test', [
    'id' => $id,
])
```

You may also want to have `env('APP_DEBUG',true)` turned on to get verbose output

Comment: there are no error message , the problem is that the image didn't load properly , and i dident use the 'id' on the image path( my path is "myImage.jpg" ), my probleme is that when i try to send a parameter to controllor  i have this problem " the image don't load properly "

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:
`href="{{ URL::to('yourfile')}}"`. Also you should place your images in **laravel public folder**. If you will create folder img in your public folder then you need to something like this: `href="{{ URL::to('img\imgname.png')}}"`.